# Вывод статей по тегу на modx revo

Tags: modx, revo

Нужно вывести список статей по тегу, вывод статей с помощью приложения Articles, что использовать для вывода страницы по тегу?

Comment: Articles - это что такое? Стандартные страницы или плагин?

Comment: Плагин, для вывода блога.

Comment: Телепатов нет, как называется, может сами написали? getresources - чаще всего используется для вывода по полю, но не обязательно.

Comment: Articles это плагин вывода статей, там есть собственное поле блога, но открывать страницу с статьями по тегу не получается.

Comment: Articles are stored as Resources in MODX https://docs.modx.com/extras/revo/articles/articles.retrieving-articles-outside-of-articles.  Т.е. делаем вывод по полю article_tags

Comment: Спасибо, большое!